# Using powershell I am importing a C# DLL.. I can only seem to call the getter but not setter methods of instances

Tags: powershell, syntax, properties

POWERSHELL CODE:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xxxx\DLL.dll")

$DLL = New-Object DLL.DLL("test","test","test","test") #This works fine and creates an instance of the object.

echo $DLL.Method()   #This outputs perfectly fine. ('butter' or whatever is comes back because its a getter method)


$DLL.Method("TestString") #This fails saying DLL.DLL does not contain a method named Method (or whatever my method name is!!) This is a setter method. Its supposed to set some variable and the other one returns it.
```

Here is my C# code:

```
namespace DLL
{


    public class DLL
    {
        private string _strRandomString


        //*************************************************************************
        //CONSTRUCTOR
        //*************************************************************************


 //Not writing code for constructor because it works 100% properly

        //*************************************************************************
        // public properties
        //*************************************************************************
        public bool Method
        {
            get { return this._strRandomString; }
            set { this._strRandomString = value; }   //!!! Unable to set the string but I can get it back!
        }

}
```

I have tried many things like making a string, then passing that into my method, doing something like $DLL::Method("string") etc.

I can't get it to set! Only get the value!

The error is:

```
Method invocation failed because [DDL.DLL] does not contain a method named 'Method'.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xxxx.ps1:31 char:1
+ $DLL::Method($test);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getter and setter methods underly *properties*, and **with *property access syntax* (`.<name>`) you *never* use `()`** - neither on getting nor on setting.

```
$DLL.Method # get the - paradoxically named - "Method" property

$DLL.Method = 'madness' # set the "Method" property, assuming it isn't read-only
```

<sup>Note: The implication is that `$DLL.Method()` could never have worked with the code in your question.</sup>

**Alternatively** - but more verbosely - you can **use *method syntax* with the `get_` and `set_`prefixes, in which case you *need* `()`**:

```
$DLL.get_Method() # same as: $DLL.Method

$DLL.set_Method('madness') # same as: $DLL.Method = 'madness'
```

While using the accessor methods is less convenient, their use is sometimes necessary: when a given instance has [ETS properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml) that *shadow* the .NET type's true properties, only the accessor *methods* provide access to the latter; e.g.:

```
$xmlDoc = [xml] '<Foo Name="bar" />'
$xmlDoc.Foo.Name # ETS property that contains the Name *attribute*'s value.
$xmlDoc.Foo.get_Name() # true [xml] property that contains the *element*'s name.
```

---

**Demonstration**:

Here's a self-contained example that demonstrates the above.

Note:

- `Method` has been renamed to `SomeProperty` to avoid confusion.
- The data type has been changed to `string` to match the type of the `_strRandomString` backing variable.

```
Add-Type @'
namespace DLL
{
    public class DLL
    {
        private string _strRandomString = "random?";
        public string SomeProperty
        {
            get { return this._strRandomString; }
            set { _strRandomString = value; }   //!!! Unable to set the string but I can get it back!
        }
      }
}
'@

$obj = [DLL.DLL]::new()
$obj.SomeProperty                # get the property 
$obj.SomeProperty = 'new value'  # set the property
$obj.SomeProperty                # get the updated value 

$obj.set_SomeProperty('even newer value') # use the setter method 
$obj.get_SomeProperty()                   # use the getter method
```

The above yields:

```
random?
new value
even newer value
```

---

As an aside: Please **avoid pseudo method syntax in PowerShell commands**: instead of

```
New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)
```

use

```
New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...
```

PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like *shell commands*, not like *methods*.

That is, ***no parentheses* around the argument list**, with i**ndividual arguments separated by *whitespace***, not `,`.

In the case of `New-Object`, you're passing a *single, array-valued argument* (implicitly) to parameter `-ArgumentList` (whose *elements* are `,`-separated).